# Ruby on Rails + EventMachine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nonblocking, eventmachine

I've heard that you have to use non-blocking code throughout the application to be able to harness true power of EventMachine.

Does this mean I can't run Ruby on Rails with EventMachine?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you to use EventMachine with Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) runs on EventMachine (and Rack, MongrelParser amongst a few others). And Rails apps run fine with thin.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a bit old, but for anyone interested in using eventmachine and RoR, I'd highly recommend checking out Ilya Grigorik's Async Rails Project https://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails he and a few other people have done a great job creating an example fully event RoR App. Plus there is a lot of resources that he links to, to learn more about what's really going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have an eventmachine run loop running in another thread (similar to this: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2011/05/04/eventmachine-and-passenger/) along with Rails and can defer work to that.